# "axis" won't add x-axis to boxplot

Tags: r, plot, axis, boxplot, label

I'm trying to make a boxplot with custom axis labels, but I can't seem to add an x-axis to the plot.

For example:

```
test <- data.frame(year=as.integer(rep(1963:2014, each=10)),
       response=rnorm(520))
boxplot(response~year, data=test, ylim=c(-3,3), xlab="", ylab="", 
    range=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
responselabs <- as.numeric(c(-3:3, by=1))
yearlabs <- as.integer(seq(1965,2015, by=5))
axis(2, at=responselabs, tck=0.03, las=1)
axis(1, at=yearlabs, tck=0.03)
```

returns the boxplot, but no x-axis labels:

[image: boxplot with no x axis]

Trying to hack it the other way by making an empty plot first, I can get the axes, but it won't add the boxplot:

```
plot(NA, ylim=c(-3, 3), xlim=c(1962, 2015), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="")
axis(2, at=responselabs, tck=0.03, las=1)
axis(1, at=yearlabs, tck=0.03)
boxplot(response~year, data=test, ylim=c(-3,3), xlab="", ylab="", 
    range=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", add=T)
```

[image: empty plot]

What's going on here?

Comment: `boxplot` probably converts `year` to a factor. try this: `axis(1, at = 1:length(unique(test$year)), labels = unique(test$year))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening is that `boxplot` converts `year` to a `factor`. We can get around this by using the `labels` argument in `axis`:

```
boxplot(response~year, data=test, ylim=c(-3,3), xlab="", ylab="", 
    range=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
responselabs <- as.numeric(c(-3:3, by=1))
yearlabs <- as.integer(seq(1965,2015, by=5))
axis(2, at=responselabs, tck=0.03, las=1)
axis(1, at = yearlabs - 1962, labels = yearlabs)
```

[image]

Comment: But this puts labels where they shouldn't be... test$year ranges from 1963-2014, but using your suggestion, the data extends to 2017

Comment: I don't think I understand, it looks to me that the data extends to 2015 on the boxplot (one to the right of 2014 box)

Comment: Sorry, it seemed like the original code didn't work right. Is it really as simple as subtracting 1962?

Comment: The key is that the location of the axis labels are integers. So you need to place the labels no according to the numeric value of the years, but along `seq_along(years)`. Thus, if the first year was 1950, then you should subtract 1949.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(test,aes(x=year,y=response,group=year))+
geom_boxplot()+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=round(seq(min(test$year),max(test$year),by=5),1))
```

[image]

If you want to be rounded to the nearest 5 then the code is fairly easy to adjust in the `scale_x_continuous()` argument.

```
p<-ggplot(test,aes(x=year,y=response,group=year))+
   geom_boxplot()+
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(round(min(test$year)/5,0)*5,round(max(test$year)/5,0)*5, by = 5),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide the interval in x-axis labels requested by OP

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I do like ggplot, I was just trying to keep this in the base plot functions to save time.

Comment: No problem @Patrick, I personally prefer ggplot for almost all my graphing needs... Every now and then though its hard to resist a call to hist() or boxplot() for exploratory purposes!

Answer (score 0):

Like others have stated, you may have confused the values underlying the x-axis. Playing around with `abline()` reveals that `abline(v=2010)` does not show up, but something like `abline(v=50)` will show up.

Here's a plot you're after, I believe (with some extra modifications):

```
year_vals <- as.integer(rep(1963:2014, each=10)) # pulling out of next line for easy reference
test <- data.frame(year=year_vals,response=rnorm(520))
boxplot(response~year, data=test, ylim=c(-3,3), xlab="", ylab="", range=0, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
responselabs <- as.numeric(c(-3:3, by=1))
yearlabs <- year_vals[year_vals%%5==0] # alternate, more general definition; note that 2015 wasn't in the original 'test' data.frame #as.integer(seq(1965,2015, by=5))
axis(2, at=responselabs, tck=0.03, las=1)
# axis(1, at=1:length(yearlabs), tck=0.03)
axis(1, at=which(unique(year_vals)%in%yearlabs), labels=unique(yearlabs), tck=0.03)
```

Comment: This seems a lot more convoluted than it needs to be.